# Ola Hallengren backup failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, jobs, ola-hallengren

I have been using on my SQL Server 2008R2 server Ola Hallengren solutions for almost two years.  Last night backups failed, both System databases and user databases with error below.

Example of system databases error:

> Date and time: 2016-05-31 20:00:01 Command: DECLARE @ReturnCode int
>   EXECUTE @ReturnCode = [master].dbo.xp_create_subdir
>   N'E:\SQLBackups\Server1\master\FULL' IF @ReturnCode <> 0
>   RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1) HResult 0x5620, Level
>   16, State 1 xp_create_subdir() returned error 183, 'Cannot create a
>   file when that file already exists.' Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1,
>   Server Server1, Line 1 Error creating directory. Outcome: Failed
>   Duration: 00:00:00 Date and time: 2016-05-31 20:00:01

User Databases error Example:

> Date and time: 2016-05-31 20:00:12 Database: [Dummy_1] Status: ONLINE
>   Standby: No Updateability: READ_WRITE User access: MULTI_USER Is
>   accessible: Yes Recovery model: SIMPLE Differential base LSN:
>   423000000014100036 Last log backup LSN: 342000000037500001   Date and
>   time: 2016-05-31 20:00:12 Command: DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE
>   @ReturnCode = [master].dbo.xp_create_subdir
>   N'E:\SQLBackups\Server1\Dummy_1\FULL' IF @ReturnCode <> 0
>   RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1) HResult 0x5620, Level
>   16, State 1 xp_create_subdir() returned error 183, 'Cannot create a
>   file when that file already exists.' Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1,
>   Server Server1, Line 1 Error creating directory. Outcome: Failed
>   Duration: 00:00:00 Date and time: 2016-05-31 20:00:12

It failed when I run the job on right click too

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure the SQL Server Service Account has the required Access Control for the paths used for storing your backups.

Check the [SQL Server Accounts and Permissions page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions#Reviewing_ACLs) for details about what ACLs are required.  See [Configure File System Permissions for database engine access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access) for details about how to change permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error today when backing up to a network-share: `RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1)`

I did a manual `BACKUP DATABASE` in SSMS. This revealed the true cause behind the error:
`Write on "\\server.domain.com\SQL\2016\SERVER$INSTANCE_PROD\master\FULL\master.bak" failed: 112(There is not enough space on the disk.)`

The disk on the network-drive was full. I didn't see it otherwise because i do not have administrative access to that device.